# Customized listView does not work

Tags: java, android, sqlite, listview, adapter

I am creating an Android app that takes tasks details from the user and insert them into database. When the user want to see the list of his tasks for the day (some of the tasks will be displayed not all the tasks), he will go to "viewTasks.java" activity that extends listActivity and use a costume adapter to display the tasks list.

The list view takes its items from a function in the database that returns `List<TodaysTask>`. Now this activity show nothing! While I am sure there is tasks inserted into the database! The customized list dose not appear with me! what is wrong here?

I also add Toast msg if the list returned from the database is not empty and this msg appears! could you please help me solving the problem?
TodaysTask class has string name,category and int time_H,time_M.

Here the ViewTasks.java that will display the days task to the user

```
public class ViewTask extends Activity implements 
    OnItemClickListener, DialogInterface.OnClickListener {

private ListView todays_task_list;
private List<TodayTasks> todaysTaskArrayList;
private CustomAdapter customAdapter;
private int clickedPosition;
SchedulerHelper schedulerHelper;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.task_view);

    schedulerHelper = new SchedulerHelper(this);
    schedulerHelper.open();

    todaysTaskArrayList = new ArrayList<TodayTasks>();
    todaysTaskArrayList = schedulerHelper.getTodayTasks();

    if (!todaysTaskArrayList.isEmpty())//has elements 
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "not empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
        .show();

    todays_task_list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.tasksList);
    customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(this, R.layout.list_row,
            todaysTaskArrayList);
    todays_task_list.setAdapter(customAdapter);
    todays_task_list.setOnItemClickListener(this);}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    todaysTaskArrayList = new ArrayList<TodayTasks>();
    todaysTaskArrayList = schedulerHelper.getTodayTasks();
    customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(this, R.layout.list_row,
            todaysTaskArrayList);
    todays_task_list.setAdapter(customAdapter);
    todays_task_list.setOnItemClickListener(this); }

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    todaysTaskArrayList = new ArrayList<TodayTasks>();
    todaysTaskArrayList = schedulerHelper.getTodayTasks();
    customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(this, R.layout.list_row,
            todaysTaskArrayList);
    todays_task_list.setAdapter(customAdapter);
    todays_task_list.setOnItemClickListener(this);}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view,
        int position, long id) {//do somethings
}}
```

task_view.xml

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/tasksList"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>
```

here is the customized adapter snippet

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<TodayTasks> {
private Context context;

public CustomAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<TodayTasks> objects) {
    super(context, resource, objects);
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = convertView;
    final int pos = position;
    if (convertView == null)
        view = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_row,
                null);

    // task name
    TextView name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.task_name);

    // category name
    TextView category = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.task_category);

    // proposed_time
    TextView time = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.proposed_time);

    TodayTasks todaysTask = getItem(position);
    name.setText(todaysTask.name);
    category.setText(todaysTask.category);
    time.setText(String.format("%02d : %02d", todaysTask.time_H,
            todaysTask.time_M));

    view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            ((ViewTask) context).startOnClick(pos);
        }
    });
    return view;
}}
```

the List_row.xml

```
 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/task_name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/assignment"/>


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/task_category"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/task_name"
    android:text="@string/university" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/proposed_time"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@id/title"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:text="@string/_16_30"/>
```

and the function in the databaseHelper that returns List snippet

```
public List<TodayTasks> getTodayTasks() {
    Cursor cursor = sqliteDatabase.query(TODAYTASKS_TABLE, null, null,
            null, null, null, null);
    ArrayList<TodayTasks> tasksInfo = new ArrayList<TodayTasks>();
    if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            tasksInfo
                    .add(new TodayTasks(
                            cursor.getString(cursor
                                    .getColumnIndex(COLUMN_NAME_TODAYTASKS_NAME)),
                            cursor.getString(cursor
                                    .getColumnIndex(COLUMN_NAME_TODAYTASKS_CATEGORY)),
                            cursor.getInt(cursor
                                    .getColumnIndex(COLUMN_NAME_TODAYTASKS_TIME_HOUR)),
                            cursor.getInt(cursor
                                    .getColumnIndex(COLUMN_NAME_TODAYTASKS_TIME_MINUTE))));

        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    if (!tasksInfo.isEmpty()) {
        cursor.close();
        return tasksInfo;
    } else {
        cursor.close();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: where is your ListView: todays_task_list ...??

Comment: @bachu in task_view layout, that associated to "View_task.java" activity

Comment: This question has three answers, but they all "didn't work" and it looks abandoned. Suggest this is closed as unclear.

Answer (score 1):

If your activity extends list activity it should then have a listview which has ID android.R.id.list

```
<ListView android:id="@id/android:list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

You can look it up with

```
ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
```

Comment: i change the id as you mention but still have the same error.

 task_view.xml:  <ListView  android:id="@+id/list"

Comment: @DkjKjb look at the example in my answe . It should be @id/android:list notice the android prefix

Comment: it gives me error on View_task.java when i try to initialize the list. "android cannot be resolved or is not a field"

Comment: task_view.xml: 
<ListView  android:id="@+id/android:list"    View_task.java: ListView todays_task_list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.android:list);   it says: Multiple markers at this line
 - list cannot be resolved or is not a field.
 - android cannot be resolved or is not a field.
 - Syntax error on token ":", . expected.   and if i delete "android:" is says: list cannot be resolved or is not a field

Comment: thank you so much, it does not crash now. but i cant make sure the customization works well because the list will task its elements from a table in the database that created by a service. the service not working if you have time please read the issue on this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26822521/service-does-not-work thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Use this oncreate your code should work.If other error does not occur then we will see.

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //remove setcontentview()
        schedulerHelper = new SchedulerHelper(this);
        schedulerHelper.open();

        todaysTaskArrayList = new ArrayList<TodayTasks>();
        todaysTaskArrayList = schedulerHelper.getTodayTasks();

        if (!todaysTaskArrayList.isEmpty())//has elements 
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "not empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
            .show();

        todays_task_list = getListView();//write this.
        customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(this, R.layout.list_row,
                todaysTaskArrayList);
        todays_task_list.setAdapter(customAdapter);
        todays_task_list.setOnItemClickListener(this);}




 @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        todaysTaskArrayList = new ArrayList<TodayTasks>();
        todaysTaskArrayList = schedulerHelper.getTodayTasks(); //this should be here
        customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(this, R.layout.list_row,
                todaysTaskArrayList);
        todays_task_list.setAdapter(customAdapter);
        todays_task_list.setOnItemClickListener(this);
       //instead of here.
       }
```

now your code should work.

Comment: same thing, toast msg appears but the list dose not!. sorry but what getListView() method does?  thanks for your help

Comment: this method gives you the implicit list of listactivity. Sice you are using listactivity or use simple activity as suggested in below answer.have you replaced my oncreate with yours.as it is thanks by the way what is your text color of list item change that also to red or something else.

Comment: i did what you said but no result. only blank activity and the toast msg

Comment: i have just edited the on resume method have you tried onresume method that i just updated.Thanks.

Comment: unfortunately it dose not work. shows blank activity and the toast msg

Answer (score 0):

Error may be here

```
if (convertView == null)
    view = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_row,
            null);
```

change to

```
if (convertView == null)
    view = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_row,
            parent);
```

Also use this inside onCreate Method

```
setListAdapter(customAdapter);
```

Inside getView callback use:

```
if(view == null){
  //inflate
}
```

instead of if(convertView == null) also below that use view instead of convertView and return view

Comment: unfortunately no changes

Comment: I cant see you using setListAdapter anywhere how will activity know how to populate list :O

Comment: i already use it. "todays_task_list.setAdapter(customAdapter);". i also change it to yours but no difference